# Keyspace doesn't appear in Opscenter Repair Service UI

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I recently updated to Datastax OpsCenter 6.1.0 and enabled the repair service against my cluster running DSE 5.0.5. The UI shows repair task status for tables in the OpsCenter keyspace, but none for the keyspace which stores all my application data. My keyspace is configured with NetworkTopologyStrategy and two replicas in each of two data centers.

How can I determine why OpsCenter is not repairing my keyspace (I don't see anything relevant in the logs)? Is there something specific I need to change in the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to OpsCenter 6.1.3, the "Subrange" area of the repair service appears to be making significant progress for the first time. It's almost to 10%, whereas previously it would only ever get to ~2% at most. I am optimistic that the upgrade has fixed the issue.